# Force boot into Linux command line

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, command-line

I am trying a number of settings on my Ubuntu 11.10 box. Unfortunately, I messed up some settings and the X window does not boot up.

I need to boot into command line to restore some settings.

However, everytime I boot, the system hangs at the Ubuntu welcome screen. All I can do is to reboot the machine.

Is there anyway I can boot into the command line directly?

Many thanks

Comment: Hopefully you got a few useful tips before the Off-Topic Police stormed the building ;)

Answer (score 12):

To switch back and forth from X to CLI is by using the virtual terminals. You can boot into X and then hit `Ctrl+Alt+<Fn>` where Fn is a function key from `F2` to `F6`. To return to X is with `Ctrl+Alt+F7`

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `grub` boot loader offers you to boot in *recovery mode*

Answer (score 0):

Even if the GUI console is messed up, you can probably  to get to text mode) virtual console 1.  Similarly,  bring you to text-mode virtual consoles 2, 3, 4, ...  You can log on to any of them - or any combination of them:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console

PS:
To boot into text-only mode (instead of the GUI), you can do this (provided, of course, you can log on!):

```
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1480813

in /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf:
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=3

in /etc/init/gdm.conf:
start on (filesystem
and started hal
and tty-device-added KERNEL=tty7
and (graphics-device-added or stopped udevtrigger)
and runlevel [!3])
stop on runlevel [016]
tech78i is offline
```

PPS:
On most other Linux variants, you'd set "default runlevel 3" by editing /etc/inittab.